# Thread id in Qt

Tags: multithreading, qt, debugging

How to print the thread id using `qDebug()` on windows environment of `Qt`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the thread id of the currently executing thread (and not the thread id of a specific QThread object):

```
qDebug() << QThread::currentThreadId();
```

Things to consider: The method returns a platform specific id (check the [docs](http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/qthread.html#currentThreadId)). In windows you cannot use this id with Win32 API functions since it returns a pseudo id and not the real thread id.

If your application will only run in Windows and you need to do something meaningful with the thread id it would probably be best if you used [GetCurrentThreadId()](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fms683183(VS.85).aspx&ei=8OYoSvDgD5m7_AbFl6jnCg&usg=AFQjCNF5CswmKqwlqiIK9FMVHwLzqdbyKQ&sig2=3689m-CKKs1CQiWlTwZR8A).

Comment: Is this still correct?  I see that currentThreadId() returns a handle ( http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#currentThread ), which presumably will be different every time it is invoked.  Would you not want to use QThread::currentThread() instead, which is a pointer to the thread data structure?

Answer (score -1):

On windows, applications normally "detatch" from the command line when you execute them. If you add

```
win32:CONFIG+=console
```

your applications will block the command prompt, and print the qDebug statements.

Answer (score -4):

Since a QThread's underlying implementation is pthreads, you can use (I"m assuming you want a usable ID)

```
pthread_t = pthread_self();
```

from within the thread that is executing.

The value returned from QThread::currentThreadId() is not portable.

Comment: What you might have meant: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qthread.html#currentThreadId

Comment: -1 Since the question specifically asks for how to retrieve the thread ID in Qt.  Qt supports multiple platforms.